# Use input value in GET request with Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: html, forms, spring-boot, servlets, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf. I have a simple form where I want the user to enter id and name.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/search/}" method="get">
   <p>Name: <input type="text" id="companyName"/></p>
   <p>Id: <input type="text" id="companyId"/></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, I want the GET request to contain the value of the id field. So for example if the user fill id "Apple" then I want the GET request to look like "url/search?id=Apple. Then my Spring controller will be able to pick it up.

```
@RequestMapping("search/{id}")
public void search(@RequestParam String id) {
   // some code here
}
```

This seems like the simplest thing yet I am unable to Google anything about it.

**Bonus question:** *(Please delete the bonus question if it violates SRP of stackoverflow's question)*

I have an object that has two attributes, name and id. The user selects a name using the input field above with an autocomplete feature. When the user submits the form, I want the id field (which will be hidden) to be populated with the id for the selected name (it's the same object).  Currently I'm using JS with "onsubmit" function that searches the array to find the right object. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: An input tag in a form typically uses the "name" attribute to achieve this. For example: `<input type="text" id="companyId" name="id">`. The name is submitted along with the input field's value (e.g. `id=12345`) when the form data is submitted (your GET). See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname). And an online demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit).

Comment: Yeah, but I am asking specifically about Spring. I am not using php.

Comment: Yes - absolutely. You don't have to use PHP - that's just a convenience for the demo I linked to. The relevant part is how forms use "name" attributes when GETting (and POSTing, etc.).